# How to refactor method which performs multiple steps (dependent on each other)?

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring

What is the best way to refactor a method which has many steps in it? For example, a method which setups some objects, creates several objects (Eg a database table), and so on - basically, one method which does a set of related steps.

Would this be best suited to the command design pattern?

Thanks

Comment: Just in case the downvoter checks this post again, I would really like to understand why you downvoted the first two answers.

Comment: What do you want the refactoring to accomplish? Normally if you have a method that's getting too big, you perform 'extract method' (http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) until it's more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is no general answer to that. But about your example of creating and setting up objects, look into the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) and the [Factory Patten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). The command pattern is useful when you have different possible actions (e.g. messages passed through a queue).

Sometimes it is also good for the readability of your code to just look for semantic units in your method and refactor them into methods, even when you do not reuse them elsewhere. A call to `NotifyAllClients` tells a reader more than a loop over some collection that calls some method.

Comment: I downvoted an incorrect one liner;  seems you fixed it so
I changed my vote.

Comment: @Pierreten: Though not required by any means, you might want to consider leaving a comment when you downvote to help improve the overall quality of SO.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes

Answer (score 2):

[Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) is the appropriate pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Other ways of refactoring than the already mentioned ones could be using Template Method design pattern to allow to extract different parts and probably exchange them if needed in future. You could as well use even the State pattern, when you would like to rearrange those different parts of the method.